# I have 3 pythons in my miniconda3/bin, which do I keep?

Tags: python, python-3.9

I'm on windows wsl2, and I have [3 pythons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rOKj3.png). Which one do I keep or should I no touch them? I was reading an article on how to fix import errors and it might be because I have more than 1 python version(more than one pip). When I type python --version and python3 --version, I get 3.9.12 on both

Comment: You have one python. All the rest are aliases.

Comment: You probably shouldn't touch them. It sounds like you are starting to head toward the [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/). Perhaps you should make a question about your primary issue instead.

Comment: Ok I'll make a new question on my actual problem, the import errors@Locke

Answer (score 0):

These are usually symbolic links. It helps resolving the main python interpreter without having to specify the full target version.

Try running `ls -l`. It should gives you something similar to this (in my case I ran `ls -l /bin/python*`):

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    7 Apr 15  2020 /bin/python -> python2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    9 Mar 13  2020 /bin/python2 -> python2.7
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 3.6M Mar  8  2021 /bin/python2.7
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    9 Feb 25  2022 /bin/python3 -> python3.8
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 5.3M Mar 15  2022 /bin/python3.8
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   33 Mar 15  2022 /bin/python3.8-config -> x86_64-linux-gnu-python3.8-config
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   16 Mar 13  2020 /bin/python3-config -> python3.8-config
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 5.8K Jan 13  2020 /bin/python3-wsdump
```